# Does Doom novelization ever explain the origin/nature of Supercharge (healing Blue Sphere)?

Tags: books, doom

Doom novel "Knee Deep in the Dead" describes the initial encounter of the protagonist with the game's Supercharge item (blue sphere that heals him).

Aside from that initial description, do any of the books have an explanation of what this item/creature is, and what is its origin?

Comment: The Doom wiki mentions them, called Soul Spheres, on the page about the novels.  http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Doom_novels

Answer (score 2):

The Doom novel '[Infernal Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_novels#Infernal_Sky)' goes into greater detail about the blue spheres. They're called "[Soul Spheres](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Sphere)" and are semi-sentient creatures (capable of replicating a blurry human face). Their primary use is evidently medical.

> Medbot found us!
>   Its voice had always been pleasant. Now it was
>   music to my ears: "Sears and Roebuck sent a message.
>   Part of your unit has been damaged."
>   I slowed down, caught my breath, tried to be
>   coherent. "We need your help. We need one of those,
>   oh, you know--the blue spheres that help sick
>   people."
>   "They are called soul spheres."
>   "How . . . appropriate," whispered Albert, hanging
>   on the edge of consciousness.
>   "Yes," Fly got into the act. "Like the one you used
>   on Hidalgo."
>   The medbot's voice was unemotional but not a
>   monotone. It could have been my imagination, but I
>   thought it sounded sorry when it said, "That was the
>   last one."

Beyond that, the only mention of the "Soul Spheres" in any detail occurs in the [Doom Manual](http://web.archive.org/web/20090317104818/http://www.steamgames.com/Manuals/2300/DOOM%20II%20Manual.pdf)

[image]